# How to texture a logo with several colors in different shapes

Tags: modeling, texturing

I am looking for way to color the letters of my Logo just like the color organization you can see in the picture attached here.

I do not plan to keep any shape of the object but only how the colors are grouped.  The problem I am facing is how to use the letters as an individual object, so I can subdivide and shade separatly.

[image]

Comment: Pretty impossible to say without any picture of your mesh. Usual ways are well explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)